# How to stop GCC complaining about "directive output may be truncated" in snprintf() call?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using GCC 9.2.0 on both an ancient Linux (RedHat 5.2) and modern macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, and I get the same complaint on both.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Example
{
    /* ... */
    char mm_yyyy[8];    /* Can't be changed */
    /* ... */
};

extern void function(struct tm *tm, struct Example *ex);

void function(struct tm *tm, struct Example *ex)
{
    snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d",
             tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_year + 1900);
}
```

When compiled with `-Wall` and any optimization (so not with `-O0` and not with no optimization option at all), the compiler says:

```
$ gcc -O -Wall -c so-code.c 
so-code.c: In function ‘function’:
so-code.c:15:49: warning: ‘%d’ directive output may be truncated writing between 1 and 11 bytes into a region of size 8 [-Wformat-truncation=]
   15 |     snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d",
      |                                                 ^~
so-code.c:15:48: note: directive argument in the range [-2147483647, 2147483647]
   15 |     snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d",
      |                                                ^~~~~~~
so-code.c:15:48: note: directive argument in the range [-2147481748, 2147483647]
so-code.c:15:5: note: ‘snprintf’ output between 4 and 24 bytes into a destination of size 8
   15 |     snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d",
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   16 |              tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_year + 1900);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$
```

At one level, fair enough; if `tm->tm_mon` contained a value outside the range 0 to 99 (or -1 to -9), then more than two bytes would be written to the output buffer, or if `tm->tm_year + 1900` required more than 4 digits, then there would be truncation/overflow.  However, the time values are known to be valid (month `0` to `11`; year + 1900 in the range `1970` to `2100`, for sake of concreteness; the range of years is actually smaller — 2019 .. 2025 or thereabouts), so the concern is not actually warranted.

Is there a way to suppress the warning without resorting to code such as:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore "-Wformat-overflow" /* Or "-Wformat-truncation" */
#endif

    snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d",
             tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_year + 1900);

#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
```

The `#ifdef` lines are necessary because the code has to be compiled by other compilers (notably XLC 13.x on AIX) which complain about unknown pragmas, even though they're not really supposed to.  (More formally, they're not required to complain and should accept the code ignoring the unknown pragma, but they pass comments about not recognizing the pragma, which defeats the goal of clean compilation.)

Just for kicks; if you change the function from returning `void` to returning `int`, and if you then `return snprintf(…);`, the error is not generated.  (This surprises me — I'm not sure I understand why this is not a problem too.  I guess it has to do with 'the return value from `snprintf()` is returned so it could be checked and the overflow spotted, therefore, but it is a bit surprising.)

Unfortunately, this is an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the code it is extracted from is much bigger, and changing the data structure is not an option — and this is just one step among many in the function where it appears.

I suppose I could write a microscopic function to call `snprintf()` and return the value (which would be ignored), but:

- Is there any other viable alternative that works?
- Is there a way to tell GCC that the range of the variables passed to `snprintf()` et al is safer than the worst case scenario?

Comment: Have you tried `(tm->tm_mon + 1)%100u, (tm->tm_year + 1900)%10000u`?

Comment: @chux: That does seem to shut it up — thanks!  It always helps to have someone else think with you (for you) when you hit a brick wall on your own.  Convert that into an answer and you'll get my tokens of gratitude.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Does this behavior only happen on `GCC 9.2.0`?

Comment: Does explicitly ignoring the return value of snprintf with a `(void)` cast stop the warning?

Comment: @ChrisDodd — it happens with 9.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.1.0 too, but not with 7.3.0 or 7.2.0.  Those are all the versions I've got on this machine; my other one has some older versions, but 8.x upwards seems to report the problem and 7.x downwards does not.  This testing was on my Mac.  The cast to `(void)` does not suppress the error.

Comment: It's almost equal to `strftime("%m-%Y")`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond — almost; the difference is a leading zero for nine months of the year, IIRC. Interesting thought, though.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: 'tis interesting — POSIX [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) does not provide a way to get the month number for Jan-Sep as a single digit number, AFAICS.  And it provides more options than standard C [`strftime()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.5) does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With compilers that  check the range of possible values, use `%` to quickly limit the range.

`% some_unsigned_N` insures the output is in  `[0... N-1]`.

Note that `% some_pos_int_N` output is in the `(-N ...N)` range so recommend  *unsigned* math to avoid the `'-'` sign.

```
snprintf(ex->mm_yyyy, sizeof(ex->mm_yyyy), "%d-%d", 
    //  tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_year + 1900);
    (tm->tm_mon + 1)%100u, (tm->tm_year + 1900)%10000u);
```

May also want to use `"%u"` should `some_unsigned_N` near `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Thank you.  This does stop the complaint, and also ensures that the values are within the expected range, and there's no reason to think other compilers will reject it, so it meets my criteria.  (It's possible that another compiler set fussy won't accept that this makes it safe — I'll cross that bridge if I get to it.  I might need to deal with complaints about mixing signed and unsigned arithmetic, but that too can be dealt with later, if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

A few other options:

- Do a range check at runtime and call `abort()` if the values are out of range. This has the advantage of being fully standard and never generating an incorrect string regardless of whether the input data is valid. It may actually be faster than computing the remainder.

  ```
  if (tm->tm_year < -1900 || tm->tm_year > 9999 - 1900)
      abort();
  ```
- Tell the compiler that the values are in range using `unreachable()` (starting in C23) or `__builtin_unreachable()` (a GCC extension). This has no overhead, but passing an invalid date would not merely generate an unexpected string; it would be undefined behavior. If you accidentally called the function as part of logging code before the date validation, then the date validation could be optimized out.

  ```
  if (tm->tm_mon < 0 || tm->tm_mon > 11)
      __builtin_unreachable();
  ```
- Use a bitmask to reduce the range of the inputs. It's cheaper than using the remainder, but isn't possible in all cases and will yield less intuitive results if the values are out of range.

  ```
  snprintf(..., (tm->tm_mon & 0xF) + 1, (tm->tm_year & 0xFFF) + 1900);
  ```

Comment: *Do a range check at runtime and call `abort()` if the values are out of range*  Oh **HELL NO!!!**  Crash the entire process because you got one bit of bad data?!?!!?  *Use a bitmask to reduce the range of the inputs. It's cheaper than using the remainder*  You know it's "cheaper" how? Even *if* true (and with deeply-pipelined CPUs executing multiple instructions at once `%` might even be faster...), in the context of an expensive call such as `snprintf()`, the loss of clarity won't be worth the infinitesimally-small benefit of such a premature micro-optimization.