# GCC warning me about directive output truncation

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I've been compiling with clang for a while, but now that I'm back with GCC (8.3), I'm getting a lot of non-fatal warnings.

For example, I have the following line of code that prints a given longitude, in a fixed-width format "(degrees)(minutes).(seconds)(W|E)".  Before this, though, I have code that calculates `degrees`, `minutes`, and `seconds` while making sure that all values are sane (e.g., that -90 ≤ `degrees` ≤ 90 no matter what).

So this compiles and runs perfectly:

```c
snprintf(pResult, 10, "%03d%02u.%02u%c", degrees, minutes, seconds, (degrees < 0 ? 'W' : 'E'));
```

However, GCC gives a lot of warnings about it:

```c
aprs-wx.c: In function ‘myFunction’:
aprs-wx.c:159:39: warning: ‘%c’ directive output may be truncated writing 1 byte into a region of size between 0 and 2 [-Wformat-truncation=]
   snprintf(pResult, 10, "%03d%02u.%02u%c", degrees, minutes, seconds, (decimal < 0 ? 'W' : 'E'));
                                       ^~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:867,
                 from aprs-wx.c:21:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:67:10: note: ‘__builtin___snprintf_chk’ output between 10 and 12 bytes into a destination of size 10
   return __builtin___snprintf_chk (__s, __n, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am fully aware that if my code fails to sanitize inputs, there may be value truncation.  How can I disable this warning, or better yet, adjust my code so that GCC won't complain even with `-Wall` set?

Comment: Related (might even be a dup): [How to stop GCC complaining about “directive output may be truncated” in snprintf() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780368/how-to-stop-gcc-complaining-about-directive-output-may-be-truncated-in-snprint)

Comment: As the person who asked the question Steve Summit cross-referenced, I can fully sympathize with you asking this question. Having to add the modulus operation to the `snprintf()` function call is at best painful, but it does do the job. I'm not sure how this can be fixed by GCC. But it is getting painful to circumvent. In some of the code I work on, I'm on the verge of having to write functions to do string concatenation because the code uses variables with largish sizes to hold much smaller strings, and then combine them — there's nominally a risk of overflow, but not in practice. Frustrating!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know nothing about the analyses gcc is doing in these cases, but I wonder if it could be placated (or if its designers could arrange for it to be placated) with a couple of preceding calls to `assert()`?

Comment: I wonder if something like an `io_assert()` could be created.  It would provide information to the following `snprintf()` statement.  In your example: `io_assert((degrees >= -90 && degrees <= +90) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes < 60) && (seconds >= 0 && minutes < 60));` or something similar.  It shouldn't be an ordinary `assert()` — but an `io_assert()` might be convertible to an `assert()` under some options (`-DIO_NDEBUG` might stop it being converted to an `assert()`, or `-DIO_DEBUG` would enable it; probably explicit enablement is better), but would give the compiler information it can use.

Comment: Another workaround would be to snprintf() to a large-enough temp buffer and add an extra copy to the final destination.(less ugly than the modulo-cap, IMHO)

Comment: @SteveSummit: see your `assert()`  and raise you an alternative.  I'm pretty sure I've tried `assert()` and it doesn't currently work.

Comment: @wildplasser: The extra copy is very undesirable, though the majority of the problems occur on error handling paths where performance is less critical than on the main execution paths.  The code I work on is multi-threaded so local stack space is limited (KiB, not MiB, in size) so stack allocation of large buffers is not allowed by the local coding rules.  There are some pre-allocated per-thread buffers that are used, but …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler snprintf() is an expensive function, anyway(probably ~10 times as expensive as a memcpy)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is your concern that in a non-debug build, the warnings would come roaring back?  Hmm.

Comment: @SteveSummit: That might be a problem. Using `assert()` has some specific connotations and local coding rules may not allow ordinary `assert()`. I'm thinking that using plain `assert()` might not be appropriate, but there would probably be complaints about including an alternative name. Also, if the code is compiled by non-GCC compilers, what should happen? So, maybe it needs to be `_GCC_io_assertion()` (reserved for the implementation; GCC is the implementation), with `#ifdef __GNUC__` / `#define io_assert(...) _GCC_io_assertion(__VA_ARGS__)` / `#else` / `#define io_assert(...)` / `#endif`.

Comment: We need to be careful — designing GCC features in SO comments is probably not a good idea.

Comment: BTW: could using/checking the return value from `snprintf()` possibly silence GCC?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes just had the same thought.  `int len = snprintf(pResult, ... ); if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof pResult)  Oops();`

Comment: @chux for `fread()`,  assignment to a (dummy)variable is enough to silence GCC. (I dont like casting to void)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I disable this warning, or better yet, adjust my code so that GCC won't complain even with -Wall set?

Use `%` to limit widths.

```
snprintf(pResult, 10, "%03d%02u.%02u%c", 
   degrees%100, minutes%100u, seconds%100u, (degrees < 0 ? 'W' : 'E'));
//          ^            ^
//        signed   ,   unsigned
// max 3 characters, max 2 characters
```

Your result may vary.

Comment: If one if looking for some efficiency. could use `minutes%64u`, but code looses clarity.