# -Wformat-truncation - can I avoid it rather than disable the warning?

Tags: c, printf, gcc-warning, format-truncation

There's this code I'm compling, which has the line:

```
snprintf(target, 11, "%02ld-%02ld-19%02ld", day, month, year);
```

... which is executed after it has been verified that all 3 values are valid; and specifically, that year is between 0 and 99.

However, recent versions of GCC, when run with `-Wextra`, complain:

```
warning: ‘%02ld’ directive output may be truncated writing between 2 and 20 bytes
into a region of size 3 [-Wformat-truncation=]
```

I would rather not entirely disable this warning; nor even disable it locally. Instead, I am wondering if I could somehow "convince" GCC of the value range for the three arguments, preventing the warning.

<sub>Yes, this is rather ugly code that reinvents the wheel, and locale-specific routines for date formatting should be used, no need to lecture me; not my code.</sub>

Comment: With your example I can only see this warning when I change the 11 to a smaller value. Can you post a small piece of code that can reproduce the warning?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534284/how-to-circumvent-format-truncation-warning-in-gcc) seems to address a related problem.

Comment: @Gerd: Thanks for the link; it's related but not a dupe, since in that case truncation is possible, and in my case - it isn't.

Comment: Which version of GCC? https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEX3@orBIWCDFKx2VVzyC1lmkXQxSH4I5FGRJyEh5NerKLbp5t7LPM6MUb0xaePI@Itt4Xti68Ju2AtxDc5CFwKUPlAPFu8S5jQG4mHN9xZjBQ9hBozAGPuWT1r/NGmi3@iIu3IpStBaQrGtP7xVi@qv2Qu5oFfqDGzSulxspzPliQVSNeIpRG7AiI6gzIffD5a6rmv5L1UDz/RnOo/9lNThM6lje@OI2dH7rF2II7LieCGD7AK9AA

Comment: Seems like the same as this one [How to stop GCC complaining about “directive output may be truncated” in snprintf() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780368/how-to-stop-gcc-complaining-about-directive-output-may-be-truncated-in-snprint) 
Even the same answer

Comment: @hko True.  I saw this post similar yet slightly different and wanted to offer more alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I could somehow "convince" GCC of the value range for the three arguments, preventing the warning.

Let the compiler know that all values used are of 1-2 digits with reduced range type, `&`, `%`, `/` or etc.

In this case, recommend unsigned math and `%`.
(Note: recall `some_int%100` results are in the range -99 to 99, up to 3 characters, hence the reason for unsigned math.)

```
char target[11];
//                               dd   -dd   -19dd   \0   0-99         0-99        0-99   
snprintf(target, sizeof target, "%02lu-%02lu-19%02lu", day%100lu, month%100lu, year%100lu);
```

A smart enough compiler will see `%` and analyse accordingly.

---

Since month and day are in the range 1-12 and 1-31, could use `month & 15, day & 31`, but that micro optimization lacks clarity.

---

If  `day%100lu` brings up an undesirable warning about mixed sign-ness, then

```
snprintf(target, sizeof target, "%02u-%02u-19%02u",
    (unsigned)day%100u, (unsigned)month%100u, (unsigned)year%100u);
```

---

**or** simply use a wider `target` ;-)

Perhaps the below if a generous buffer is not prohibitive.

```
#define CHAR_PER_LONG_N (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(long)/3+3)
#define DATE_FMT %02ld-%02ld-19%02ld"
#define BUF_N (sizeof DATE_FMT + 3*CHAR_PER_LONG_N)
char target[BUF_N];

snprintf(target, sizeof target, DATE_FMT, day, month, year);
```

Comment: So, you're suggesting introducing a redundant expensive instruction... I guess that'll work, but it's kind of a crooked thing to do. :-(

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica or simply a wide buffer - no "expensive" instruction.